# Downloading a file from Django template on click doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I tried multiple ways to download a file on click from a Django template, but the download just won't start. Here's my view where I get the file path:

```
def success(request):
    model_file_path = request.session.get('model_file_path')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render(request, "success.html", {'filepath': model_file_path})
    else:
        return render(request, "success.html", {'filepath': model_file_path})
```

And here is what I tried in the success template with no success:

```
 <a href='{{filepath}}' download>download</a>
```

```
 <a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{filepath}}' download={{filepath}}>download</a>
```

```
 <a href='{{filepath}}' download={{filepath}}>download</a>
```

It just won't trigger a download, although the path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use FileResponse from django.http from django.http import FileResponse.

...

```
    return FileResponse(open(model_file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
else:
    return FileResponse(open(model_file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
```

Edit:

```
def success(request):
    model_file_path = request.session.get('model_file_path')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render(request, 'success.html')
    else:
        return FileResponse(open(model_file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)

<a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{filepath}}' download={{filepath}}>download</a>
```

Comment: This works for downloading the file, but it doesnt render my success template, is there a way to render the template and only when I click the download button it downloads the file?

Comment: Try the edit, is that what you are after?